# Is there a simple way to show that wreath product is associative?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Is there a simple way to show that wreath product is associative?

If your proof is short, please write it explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Ergin, and welcome to math.SE! At this site we generally want the question post to stand on its own, so even if the title is self-explanatory we ask that you put it again in the question post any way. I've edited your question to do this.

Comment: Well, if you know that the semidirect product of two groups is associative then you're done, as the wreath product is a special kind of semidirect product.